# SASS & LESS - extending a separated Class

Tags: css, sass, less, extend

Just wanted to know if there exist any way to extend just first two of separated Class like in example, or either exist any other option like creating a specific Class
`.background{background:red}` and use it as extension instead of a separated Class (but i don't wanted to output in CSS a class .background).

**EXAMPLES**:

**SASS:**

```
.foo {
  background:red
}
.foo {
  color:red
}
.bar {
  @extend .foo;
}
.foo {
  font-size: 16px
}
```

**LESS:**

```
.foo {
  background:red
}
.foo {
  color:red
}
.bar {
  &:extend(.foo);
}
.foo {
  font-size: 16px
}
```

The output in **CSS** will be:

```
.foo, .bar {
  background: red;
}

.foo, .bar {
  color: red;
}

.foo, .bar {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

**But I want to be like this:**

```
.foo, .bar {
  background: red;
}

.foo, .bar {
  color: red;
}

// No .bar class here

.foo {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

What way should i follow to make this happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your inheritance backwards. `bar` does not extend `foo`, `foo` extends `bar`:

<sub>LESS:</sub>

```
.bar {
  background-color: red;
}

.bar {
  color: red;
}

.foo {
  &:extend(.bar);
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Produces

<sub>CSS:</sub>

```
.bar,
.foo {
  background-color: red;
}
.bar,
.foo {
  color: red;
}
.foo {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Could you not also combine the two `.bar` declarations in your LESS code to one selector?

Comment: @TylerH, yes, but I was following OP's example as close as possible.

Comment: Hi zzzzBov, thanks for your reply! I may have created the question wrong but, i wanted something different. In your LESS code, you put the `font-size` inside the class `.foo` and your **expand** rule only expand class `.bar` (i know this). But i wanted to know if can we **expand** without loading all separated `.bar`, loading only the two before **expand** calls it and the other which was bottom not to be loaded on **expand**... Hope you understand what i really want :)

Comment: @JoziBashaj, I understood your question the first time, and you can't do what you're after in the way you're after it, which is why I indicated that you've got your inheritance backwards. The way you're modeling your styles is probably backwards. Consider just using mixins to share the common styles between `.foo` and `.bar`.